# What is "Transaction as Proof of Stake" (TAPOS) and when would a smart contract use it?

Tags: smart-contract

From: ./contracts/eosiolib/transaction.h

```
/**
 * Gets the block number used for TAPOS on the currently executing transaction.
 *
 * @brief Gets the block number used for TAPOS on the currently executing transaction.
 * @return block number used for TAPOS on the currently executing transaction
 * Example:
 * @code
 * int tbn = tapos_block_num();
 * @endcode
 */
int tapos_block_num();
```

Answer (score 3):

> What is “Transaction as Proof of Stake” (TAPOS)

A mechanism where each transaction includes a partial hash from previous blocks on the same chain.

From [the whitepaper](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#transaction-as-proof-of-stake-tapos):

> The EOS.IO software requires every transaction to include part of the
>   hash of a recent block header. This hash serves two purposes:
>
> 1. prevents a replay of a transaction on forks that do not include the referenced block; and
> 2. signals the network that a particular user and their stake are on a specific fork.
>
> Over time all users end up directly confirming the blockchain which
>   makes it difficult to forge counterfeit chains as the counterfeit
>   would not be able to migrate transactions from the legitimate chain.

> and when would a smart contract use it?

I believe its main use will come once inter-blockchain communication (IBC) is available, and it will be required to know on which chain a transaction was pushed.